# (C++) Trying to print out char* array (I think)

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have these two arrays:

```
const char *face[] =
{"Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five",
 "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten",
 "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace", "\0"};

const char *suit[] = { " of Hearts", " of Clubs", " of Diamonds", " of Spades", "\0" };
```

And actually, since I'm not even that good in C++, I don't even know when you use an asterisk in your arrays or wherever else... Would appreciate it could someone explain that too..

But anyway, the problem is that I'm trying to print out all the possible cards with their suits like this:

```
for (int n = 0; n<strlen(*suit); n++){ //where strlen(*suit) should be 4
for(int i = 0; i<strlen(*face); i++){ //where strlen(*face) should be 13
        cout << endl << face[i] << suit[n] << endl;
    }
}
```

Using that code, my program is crashing. What am I doing wrong? (It works when using n<4 and i<13, but I want it to actually work if I add or remove items from the array)

Answer (score 2):

The function `strlen` is passes a `const char*`, a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters. You cannot use it to work out the length of an array of strings.

Instead I suggest you do it like this:

```
const char *face[] =
    {"Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five",
     "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten",
     "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace", NULL};
```

So, the sentinel is the null pointer. The loop like this:

```
for (int i=0; face[i]; i++)
    // do something with face[i]
```

And likewise for the other array, of course.

---

Now, all that said, you are going about this the wrong way for a C++ program.

- Instead of using C string, pointers to character arrays, use `std::string`.
- Instead of using raw arrays to hold your strings, use the standard container classes. In your case you want `std::vector<std::string>`.

The best advice I can give you is to forget the C way of doing things, and try to learn the idiomatic C++ way to write code.

Comment: Well, time to get familiar.

Comment: nevermind! This worked perfectly, thanks.. I'll start learning about vectors

Comment: Yeah, the `face[i]` termination test in the for loop relies on the sentinel value being the null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

A few things!
You could do this check:

`sizeof(suit)/sizeof(suit[0])`

but it will run one time longer than you need, because you do have a null terminator. So either remove the null terminating string from suit and use the above or change your for to:

`for (int n = 0; strlen(suit[n]); n++)`

Likewise on the face array.

Answer (score 0):

The length of the array is not given by `strlen`, because its elements are not `char`, but `char*`. In other words, your array isn't a string.

You need to store the array length in a separate variable, or just use the `std::vector<const char*> face;` container and use `face.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

An array of pointers is not the same as an array of char. `strlen( *suit )` returns the length of the first element of the `face` array, which is a string. The length of the string at that index is 11 (including the terminating character) which is why it will only loop 11 times. Similarly, the inner loop runs only 5 times because the length of the string at the first element of `face` is 6 characters long.

You should use a vector of `std::string` instead:

```
std::vector<std::string> suit{"Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five",
 "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten",
 "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};


std::vector<std::stirng> face{" of Hearts", " of Clubs", " of Diamonds", " of Spades"};

for (auto a : suit)
{
    for (auto b : face)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const char *face[] =
   {"Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five",
     "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten",
      "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace", "\0"};
```

is an array of string literals. You'd better declare `face` as follows:

```
string face[13]= {"Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five",
     "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten",
     "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
```

You don't need that "\0" anymore since you are not dealing with c-string (char array).

You can so similar thing for `suit`.

```
 string suit[4] = { " of Hearts", " of Clubs", " of Diamonds", " of Spades"};
```

You can print those two string arrays as follows:

```
  for (int n = 0; n<13; n++){ //where strlen(*face) should be 13
      for(int j = 0; j< 4; j++){ //where strlen(*suit) should be 4
          cout << endl << face[n] << suit[j] << endl;
      }
  }
```

Comment: But I'm trying to find a way not to use just 13 and 4, for the values to change if I change my arrays

Comment: @user2280214 then you should follow David's post.

Answer (score 0):

Your counters are wrong

```
 for (int n = 0; n<4; n++){ 
    for(int i = 0; i<13; i++){ 
        cout << endl << face[i] << suit[n] << endl;
    }
 }
```

you could do it this way, too

```
 for (int n = 0; strlen(suit[n]) > 0; n++){
    for(int i = 0; strlen(face[i]) > 0; i++){
        cout << endl << face[i] << suit[n] << endl;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing arrays of pointers.  * in font of a pointer de-references that pointer and returns the string.  So, your first call to strlen(*suit) returns 10 which will result in an index that is out of bounds which causes your program to crash.